# Updating database at certain time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to make my Firebase Database update at a particular time.

The way it should work is that, for a group, the leader sets a deadline time. The group votes on some stuff. At the deadline time, I would like the database to automatically tabulate the votes and store the response within.

I'm not sure how to set these types of rules for the database without doing a check whenever a member of the group is online and refreshes their feed. Also, this would allow any member to write to the vote-result field, which seems bad when I want it to just be automatic. It seems like there should be an easier way than this, but I just can't find anything.

It seems like the other option would be to set up a separate server that counts through all the time-frames and sends an update request when the time has allotted. But it seems like Firebase should have this built in. I'm sure I'm missing something. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is a more comprehensive look at my usecase. I am looking into cron stuff now, as I think it will solve my problem, but I don't know.

1) Leader creates a group and invites friends to it. Event is created is firebase database. Group is created with a specific deadline.

2) Before deadline, leader and friends can vote on certain options. Basically they submit a dictionary to database with their votes.

3) On deadline, either just need to change the state of the group (from voting to closed) or calculate the vote response. Same problem, which is that I don't know to do do it at a certain time w/o using user clients.

Comment: Use [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and a cron task that triggers the function[1](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) [2](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) [3](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron)? Use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) to do a POST/PATCH/DELETE op on anything older than X and trigger that with any process that can do an HTTPS request?

Comment: Note that this is probably an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Members can post much more relevant answers if you start by describing the use case instead of the proposed solution.

Comment: This seems like it is in the right direction, I am looking into it. For clarity purposes, I had elaborated on my issue in the main post.

Comment: Here is another solution I have thought up: Users can only submit votes until the deadline time (which can be controlled locally) and if the deadline time has passed, then we show the vote-result (again controlled locally). It's not quite as secure (users can change their votes after deadline time if they bypass time safety), but the worst case scenario isn't bad and it works generally.